# Git view another branch

Tags: git

I checked out a new branch `my_branch` from `master` to create a new feature for my app, but I break another feature while doing it.

I don't want to delete changes in `my_branch` but want to go back to master to see the original state of broken feature. Then, I want to go back to my_branch again.

How should I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can `git stash` and go back to master see and come back and `git stash pop`

2) You can do `git show master:path/to/file` and see the file / directory ( this if you want to see the contents )

3) You can always just commit, change branch and come back and `git reset HEAD~`

Comment: Thank you. I do need to reset master to HEAD and run the app to see if the broken functionality actually works in master. Is it OK if I commit on `my_branch`, checkout master, reset HEAD, run the app, then checkout my_branch again and continue to work on branch?

Comment: @AdamNYC - Why do you want to reset HEAD? HEAD is the tip, if you reset to some other commit, that becomes HEAD. You don't reset to HEAD, as what you want is take care of by the checkout.

Answer (score 2):

- First make sure you don't have any outstanding changes in `my_branch` by using either `git commit` or `git stash`.
- Then use `git checkout master` to switch and look at the state of your code in `master`.
- When you are done, use `git checkout my_branch` to return to your branch.
- If you stashed your working changes in the first step, you can now use `git stash pop` to reapply them.